# HttpStatusCode enumeration does not have 507 (InsufficientStorage)

Tags: c#, .net, http

According to [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) there are more standard status codes such as 507 (InsufficientStorage). I am writing a webdav server library and I am using HttpStatusCode enumeration in my classes. In a part of my code I have to create a response with 507.

Is it a good practice to create another enumeration and do not use .NET HttpStatusCode enum?

Comment: Well, the root of the problem is using an `enum` to represent a dynamic set of values.  If you switch to a custom `enum` you'll end up with the same problem eventually.  If there were a "best practice" it would be to use individual constants (integer values is really a *magic number* smell).

Comment: Just follow the link to the RFC 7231 document that the IANA page uses as a reference.  It also doesn't have 507.  These RFCs are just proposals, it doesn't mean that everybody necessarily implements them.  Stick with the ones you find in HttpStatusCode and everybody will understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Just about any existing library you'll find that works with HTTP will either just use the basic data types (such as int for status code or string for method) or will use an enum but provide overloads that let you fall back to the basic data type - because whilst the enum may encapsulate the *common* values, HTTP is inherently extensible.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think it is a good idea because almost every webdav client refers to rfc2518 that noticed 507 as a meaningful result.

Comment: @HansPassant The link that you are referring to is about the *registration procedure*. It's perfectly fine for a status code not to be listed in 7231 as long it's properly registered in the IANA registry.

Comment: I am more comfortable with @Damien_The_Unbeliever comment. Would you please create an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either switch to an integer, or make your own enumeration that you can control. Like you mentioned, there are many more possible HTTP status codes than the built-in .NET enumeration has.

Comment: Actually they changed to using 429 now